# Is it valid to use numpy.gradient to find slope of line as well as slope of curve at any point?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gradient-descent, numpy, derivation

what is the difference between slope of the line and slope of the curve? Is it valid to use `numpy.gradient` to find the slope of the line and slope of the curve  at any point?

```
    #slope of line at any point 
    tanθ= y2-y1/x2-x1

    #slope of curve at any point 
    tanθ  =dy/dx
```

is it valid to use numpys `np.gradient()` to get both slopes of curve and line ? or is it meant only to find the slope of line?

Reference [slope of line vs curve](https://brilliant.org/wiki/slope-of-a-curve-basic/)

Answer (score 3):

> what is the difference between slope of line and slope of curve

It is really a matter of perspective. The slope of a line is the same over the entire span of that line, i.e. until the line changes direction. The slope of a curve is like the slope of millions of **tiny lines** all connected, so the slope is only the same value over *tiny spans*. So we can only talk about the slope of a curve at a give point (e.g. a given x value) and then we normally talk about the *gradient* of the line at that point.

---

Using your words, the gradient computed by [**numpy.gradient**](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) is the **slope** of a *curve*, using the differences of consecutive values.

However, you might like to imagine that your changes, when measured over smaller and smaller distances, *become* the **slope** (by your definitions). So when e.g. `x2 - x1` almost reaches zero, you have the same meaning as $dx$.

### Coarse example with 10 points

Here is a coarse example of `numpy.gradient`, where $dx$ has s size of `1` (equally spaced values):

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: N = 10                                  # Use ten samples
In [4]: x = np.linspace(0, np.pi*2, N)          # Equally spaced x values
In [5]: y = np.sin(x)                           # Corresponding sine values
In [6]: grads = np.gradient(y)                  # compute the gradients
```

Plotting the values and the gradients - I shifted the gradients by `0.5` to the right, so their values line up with the middle of the segment for which they describe the slope:

```
In [7]: fig, ax = plt.subplots()           
In [8]: ax.plot(x, y, "-b", label="values")                  # the y values
        ax.plot(x + 0.5, grads, "--r", label="gradients")    # the computed gradients
        plt.legend()
In [9]: plt.show()
```

[image: Gradients with only 10 sample points]

### Fine example with 1,000,000 points

Now we do example same as before, just use one million points: `N = 1_000_000`.
The blue line would look much more like a true sine wave, but the red line is now measuring the gradient with a much higher resolution than before, giving us the exact value at 1,000,000 points - for each tiny line segment of the blue line.

[image: fine grained gradients]

So the gradient values look like they are all zero! Well this is just because we made `x2-x1` become almost zero (`1 / 1e6`), so the values of `y2 - y1` also were essentially zero! We have started to approximate $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Let change the axis scale to see that the gradients do still match the pattern we might expects, and are indeed very smooth - looking like a curve:

[image: Fine grained gradients]

Much better  :)

(Notice the scale difference - `1e-6`).

---

Here are a few explanations of [**what `np.gradient` really does**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24633618/what-does-numpy-gradient-do).